# Ошибка: CS7036 Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру

Tags: c#, наследование

Что не так с моим кодом?

Смотрел разные решения, так и не понял. Отсутствует аргумент, "name" из "Drone.Drone.

```
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vehicle drone = new Drone();
        Vehicle archer = new Archer();
        drone.DisplayInfo();
        archer.DisplayInfo();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
 class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Weapon { get; set; }
    public int PowerScore { get; set; }
    public int EngenePower { get; set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public Vehicle()
    { }
    public virtual void DisplayInfo() { }
    
}
 class Drone : Vehicle
{
    public Drone(string name, int vehicleId, string weapon, int powerScore, int engenePower)
    {
      VehicleId = 001;Name = "Droncarrier";PowerScore = 5000;Weapon = "drone Fuse";EngenePower = 540;
    }
    public override void DisplayInfo()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(VehicleId + " with " + Name + " has " + PowerScore + " and carrys weapon " + Weapon + " engine " + EngenePower);
    }
}
 class Archer : Vehicle
{
    public Archer(string name, int vehicleId, string weapon, int powerScore, int engenePower)
    {           
      VehicleId = 003;Name = "Miniarcher";PowerScore = 5000;Weapon = "crossbow";EngenePower = 430;
    }
    public override void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VehicleId + " with " + Name + " has " + PowerScore + " and carrys weapon " + Weapon + " engine " + EngenePower);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У классов `Drone` и `Archer` конструкторы только с параметрами, о чём и говорит компилятор. А вот никакой ошибки про `name` в приведённом коде нет.

https://ideone.com/IX8EA2

> prog.cs(5,25): error CS1729: The type `Drone' does not contain a constructor that takes `0' arguments
> prog.cs(26,12): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

> prog.cs(6,26): error CS1729: The type `Archer' does not contain a constructor that takes `0' arguments
> prog.cs(37,12): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)